# Used anonymous references, can I pull data from them?

Tags: java, user-interface

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class GUI extends JFrame{
        String fields[] = {"Name", "Address 1", "Address 2", "City", "State", "Zip Code"};
        ArrayList<JPanel> pannelArray;
        public GUI(){
            pannelArray = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
            addJPanels();
            for(int i = 0; i<pannelArray.size(); ++i){
                add(pannelArray.get(i));
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            GUI window = new GUI();
            window.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 1));
            window.setTitle("Enter Your Shipping Address");
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setSize(400, 800);
            window.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void addJPanels(){
            for(int i = 0; i<fields.length; ++i){
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
                panel.add(new JLabel(fields[i]));
                panel.add(new JTextField(""));
                pannelArray.add(panel);
            }
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JButton("cancel"));
            panel.add(new JButton("okay"));
            pannelArray.add(panel);
        }
```

I used that code to create a simple GUI for my class.  The following question has asked me to implement the GUI to create a class using the information inside the JTextAreas. I'm quite aware of how to pull data out of a JTextArea, but seeing as I used anonymous references, I'm not sure if it's possible anymore.  If not, I'll need to go back to the drawing board to see how I can make this work.  A simple point in the right direction would be great, I'm not asking anyone to do my homework for me.

Comment: Your question is not clear. There is no JTextArea in the above code, and I don't know what you mean by "anonymous references"

Comment: Sorry, I meant JTextField, not area.  When I created them, I didn't give them a specific name, thus the term anonymous reference.

Comment: You mean that you didn't assign them to any field (instance variable) of your object, right? Well, if you need to use them later, you'd better do that.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought I'd have to do, just making sure.  Anonymous references must just be a term used by my professor, sorry for the miscommunication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using a `String` array of `fields`, why not create an array of `JTextFields`:

```
JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[fields.length];
```